# Word Check w/ Div Number Detection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make the randomizer project I'm working on be able to detect the word that's present, and based on that word, the answers will differ. For example, if:

```
  <div id="randomizer">
    <div id="wordOutput">
      <div id="button">
        <!-- This is the button that calls the getRandom() function to create the word. --><button id="myBtn">Randomize!</button><br>
        <caption>Click this button to generate a random word!
        </caption>
        <!-- This is apart of the Randomizer tool, which can be changed to fit the words. It will output the answers based on  -->
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="answers" class="answers">
      <table>
        <p id="outputNumber" class="outputNumber">Your word will go here; Click the Randomize Button! <!-- LETS SAY THIS OUTPUTS TO "Word 1" --></p>
        <div class="output" id="output1"></div>
        <div class="output" id="output2"></div>
        <div class="output" id="output3"></div><br>
        <div class="output" id="output4"></div>
        <div class="output" id="output5"></div>
        <div class="output" id="output6"></div><br>
        <div class="output" id="output7"></div>
        <div class="output" id="output8"></div>
        <div class="output" id="output9"></div>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then I want the answers to change to: (KEEP IN MIND THAT THE ANSWERS ARE RANDOMIZED AND BY DEFAULT ARE SET TO ANSWER#)

```
  <div id="randomizer">
    <div id="wordOutput">
      <div id="button">
        <!-- This is the button that calls the getRandom() function to create the word. --><button id="myBtn">Randomize!</button><br>
        <caption>Click this button to generate a random word!
        </caption>
        <!-- This is apart of the Randomizer tool, which can be changed to fit the words. It will output the answers based on  -->
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="answers" class="answers">
      <table>
        <p id="outputNumber" class="outputNumber">Word 1</p>
        <div class="output" id="output1">Answer 1 <!-- becomes "Apple"--></div>
        <div class="output" id="output2">Answer 2 <!-- becomes "Banana"--></div>
        <div class="output" id="output3">Answer 3 <!-- becomes "Rock"--></div><br>
        <div class="output" id="output4">Answer 4 <!-- becomes "Stone"--></div>
        <div class="output" id="output5">Answer 5 <!-- becomes "Milk"--></div>
        <div class="output" id="output6">Answer 6 <!-- becomes "Juice"--></div><br>
        <div class="output" id="output7">Answer 7 <!-- becomes "Grapes"--></div>
        <div class="output" id="output8">Answer 8 <!-- becomes "Tomato"--></div>
        <div class="output" id="output9">Answer 9 <!-- becomes "All of the Above"--></div>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

(KEEP IN MIND THAT THE ABOVE CODE IS THE CURRENT & WORKING FUNCTIONAL CODE)And I'm trying to work a code that grabs the div element while trying to have the id of all answer div's set to "output" and not with a number after it. So this is a code I attempted to write, yet failed horribly...

```
function checkWord()  {
  answers = [document.getElementById("output[i]").innerHTML];
  word = document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)  {
    if (word == "Word 1")  {
      answers[0] = "Possible Answer 1"
    }
    else {
      word = "Error Answer :c"
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't finish it for example purposes; how can I make this work? Sorry for the little-detail post; I was in a hurry writing this. Please comment if you need more info. Here's the whole code generating the stuff.

```
/*function playSound()  {

}
*/
/* This section is for the first tool; the Randomizer.*/
/* This is the new function for getting a random number; also used in the getRandomAnswer() function. To select different numbers, adjust the range. */
function getRandom() {
  var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var gen_nums = [];

  function in_array(array, el) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
      if(array[i] == el) return true;
    return false;
  }

  function get_rand(array) {
    var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!in_array(gen_nums, rand)) {
      gen_nums.push(rand); 
      return rand;
    }
    return get_rand(array);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    return (get_rand(nums));
  }
}
function timeOut(){
  /* This can be ignored, as it was a testing function for creating, making, and fixing the randomizer tool, but may change based on creating new tools that need to be troubleshooted. */
  setTimeout (changeRandom, 1);
}
/* This is the function that grabs the innerHTML (what the box says) of the #output1 and changes that number to the word specified. [In example, if the number [randomly] generated was 5, then this function detects that the number was 5 and changes it to Word 5.]  */
function changeRandom()  {
  /* Using the "var x" command, this tells the function that whenever there's an x in the code, it will read it as "document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML", and will grab whatever is inside that #output1 element. */
  var x = document.getElementById('outputNumber').innerHTML
  /* Here's the tutorial for modifying this tool for the possible answers. This tool [by default] has it set to  */
  if(x == 1)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 1";
  } else if(x == 2)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 2";
  } else if(x == 3)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 3";
  } else if(x == 4)  {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 4" 
  } else if(x == 5) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 5"
  }
  else if(x == 6) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 6"
  } 
  else if(x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 7"
  }
  else if(x == 8) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 8"
  }
  else if(x == 9) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 9"
  }
  else if(x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = "Word 10"
  }
  /* If the function is broken [by user modifications], it will output "Error :c", which means the user should check their modifications. */
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Error :c"
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML = getRandom(); changeRandom();})
function testFunction()  {
  if(document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML == 3)  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Three";
  }
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "N3"
  }
}
function getRandomAnswer() {
  var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var copy = nums.slice();

  for (var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var rand = copy[ j ];

    // remove from array
    copy.splice(j, 1);

    // add to output
    document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rand;
  }
  //return gen_nums;
  //document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = getRandomAnswer();
}
function changeRandomAnswer()  {

  var answers = document.getElementById("answers");

  for(var i = 0, len = answers.children.length; i < len; i++) {
    var output = answers.children[i];
    var answer = output.innerHTML;

    if(answer == "1")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 1";
    }
    else if(answer == "2")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 2";
    } 
    else if(answer == "3")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 3";
    } 
    else if(answer == "4")  {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 4" 
    } 
    else if(answer == "5") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 5"
    }
    else if(answer == "6") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 6"
    } 
    else if(answer == "7") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 7"
    }
    else if(answer == "8") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 8"
    }
    else if(answer == "9") {
      output.innerHTML = "Answer 9"
    }
  }

}
function checkWord()  {
  answers = [document.getElementById("output[i]").innerHTML];
  word = document.getElementById("outputNumber").innerHTML;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)  {
    if (word == "Word 1")  {
      answers[0] = "Possible Answer 1"
    }
    else {
      word = "Error Answer :c"
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){ getRandomAnswer(); changeRandomAnswer();})
```